# springmvc http session check and return html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

There is a bunch of static `.html` files in my project.

I want to do intercept all `*.html` requests and check their `HttpSession` to see if token is correct.

**The problem is** 
if I intercept all `*.html` path in one servlet, after auth checking, I can't redirect them to corresponding real `*.html` because it will return to the interceptor, it will be a infinite loop.

**How do i configure the project to avoid this loop?**

Comment: If you are using spring you should probably check spring-security.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I have build a spring security project now, but it still seems to have such a infinite loop problem...